# Does MySQL short-circuit the ORDER BY clause?

Tags: mysql

Given this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY mycolumn, RAND()
```

Assuming that `mycolumn` happens to only contain unique values (and hence, contains enough information to perform the `ORDER BY`), does MySQL short-circuit the operation and skip evaluating the rest?

Comment: wicked question, never thought about that even being possible, regardless of the underlying DBMS

Comment: Just spend 15 minutes ripping through Postgresql source code, can't seem to pinpoint any exact answer :( Wouldn't even have answered your question with regards to mysql though, I'll be checking back on this though

Comment: It would be an unusual optimization to put in - generally, ORDER BY against multiple columns will be forming groups of rows based on the first column, and then further sorting within those groups based on second column, etc. Given that that's the expected usual usage, why would they optimize for a different usage (where extra columns are apparently superfluous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the answer. Mysql uses different plans and can't perform lazy evaluation (o "hort-circuit").

```
mysql> explain select * from avatar  order by id;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | avatar | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 28777 |       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from avatar  order by id, name;
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra          |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | avatar | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 28777 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> explain select * from avatar  order by id, RAND();
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | avatar | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 28782 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Experience shows that it does not, even if `mycolumn` is the primary key.