# Does order matter in MySQL for short circuiting of predicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have to run the SQL query:

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 AND condition4
```

Is that any different than

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE condition3 AND condition1 AND condition4 AND condition2
```

?

---

If it's not different:

I know from my own experience that `condition1` is less expensive than `condition2` is less expensive than `condition3` is less expensive than `condition4`.

If any of the prior conditions are not met, the remaining conditions should never be checked. It wouldn't be immediately obvious to the optimizer, as stored functions are involved. How should I write a query that does this?

Comment: "Is that any different than" --- No.

Comment: I've noticed that MySQL 8 seems to have suddenly changed how short circuit evaluation works, and that the right hand side of the expression is now also (first) being evaluated in  a query that was find in MySQL 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, MySQL *probably* evaluates the conditions in order -- assuming that you have only one table in the query.  If the conditions are between tables, then all bets are off.

Your question is unclear in some respects.  If some of the conditions can be resolved at compile-time, then they often will (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/where-optimizations.html)).  Once an expression evaluates to FALSE in a chain of `AND`s, then it doesn't need to further evaluate expressions.

Without explicit documentation, you can fall back on the ANSI definition of evaluation order.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated) is a question about that specific topic.  This basically says that there is no guarantee on the order of evaluations.  It does suggest that:

```
where ((((condition1 and condition2) and condition3) and condition4)
```

would guarantee evaluation in a particular order.  I suspect that redundant parentheses would be dropped during the compile phase, and the ANSI condition is not quite as clear as it seems.

The only expression that *guarantees* order of evaluation in SQL is the `case` expression.  Although I am not a fan of using `case` in the `where` clause you could do:

```
where (case when not condition1 then 0
            when not condition2 then 0
            when not condition3 then 0
            else not condition4
       end)
```

This would guarantee order of evaluation.

By the way, for the operators and functions in MySQL, the time for an operation is not going to matter, compared to the time for retrieving the rows.  Of course, there are exceptions.  In particular, any pattern matching on long strings is going to be rather expensive.  And, calls to functions may be very expensive as well.

Answer (score 0):

The place to start investigating is with [`explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html), which will show you what the optimizer does for your particular query.

Several examples are available for study; these seem useful:

- [Using EXPLAIN to Write Better MySQL Queries](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)
- [Explaining MySQL's EXPLAIN](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/explaining-mysqls-explain)
- [Analyzing Queries for Speed with EXPLAIN](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Analyzing-Queries-for-Speed-with-EXPLAIN/)

Given those tools, others state that MySQL does short-circuit queries:

- MySQL [12.3.3 Logical Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html) developer's comment says

  > The documentation doesn't **say** anything about this, but it **appears** (based on some tests I just ran) that MySQL short-circuits evaluation of logical operators just like most other languages do.

although the related order-by may not be:

- [Does MySQL short-circuit the ORDER BY clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641852/does-mysql-short-circuit-the-order-by-clause)

However, as noted in the MySQL documentation *comments*, the documentation itself is not explicit.  You would have to use the appropriate tools and rely upon repeatable behavior of the optimizer to determine the actual state of affairs.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at the moment. Does MySQL short circuit or not?

Comment: It shows what the optimizer *does*. I'll expand slightly.

Comment: The information is either in developer's comments or in documentation; I'm adding what I find.

Comment: And what you found is wrong. Your answer is harmful (since it states what is simply not correct).

Comment: It's hard to prove something that does not exist. You cannot prove lack of something. There is nothing about it in documentation since it's not implemented.

Comment: @zerkms A single counter example would prove that it does not reliably evaluate predicates in order and short circuit when the first one is false.

Comment: Either you *know* or you  do *not*.

Comment: I do know it. It's not there, and the links provided here are wrong (most of them confuse predicate simplification and short circuiting, which are not the same thing)

Comment: @MartinSmith "A single counter example would prove that it does not reliably evaluate predicates in order and short circuit when the first one is false" --- prove that it exists. Whoever makes a positive statement must prove it.

Comment: @zerkms So is your understanding that MySQL doesn't reliably short circuit? Or just that it is not documented to do so and thus can't be relied on?

Comment: @MartinSmith I know that there is no such a thing as a short circuiting. There is predicate optimisation which you and guys on the provided links confuse it with http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/where-optimizations.html But those are **COMPLETELY DIFFERENT** optimisation techniques. You cannot use the terms interchangeably. "So is your understanding that MySQL doesn't reliably short circuit?" -- short circuiting makes **NO SENSE** for a declarative language, since it's imperative by the nature.

Comment: I'm not using the terms interchangeably. To me short circuiting would not be continuing to evaluate conditions C and D if A or B were false. And yes I know that from a SQL perspective it doesn't make sense as SQL is declarative and "all at once" but we are talking about a specific implementation here. MySQL does lots of things that aren't truly relational.

Comment: Well, that does not happen in mysql. The constant falsy expressions are eliminated during optimisation step that is not a short circuiting. And that elimination does not depend on the operands order (so it is not a "short circuiting" which operates by the order by definition).

Comment: And what about the predicates that remain as they can't be determined at optimisation time? Are they short circuited or will MySQL doggedly evaluate all of them at runtime?

Comment: "as they can't be determined at optimisation time?" --- if they cannot be eliminated - they will be applied to every row/index. "doggedly evaluate all of them at runtime" --- if it relies on runtime (either data or other environment) - how can you evaluate it statically? If you are particularly asking about short circuiting in the final `WHERE` clause - you cannot state anything about that: the final clause may look entirely different to what you have queried. So you cannot say that "your query is short circiuted" since it was rewritten by an optimizer.

Comment: Who said anything about evaluating statically? The point of short circuiting is that you don't need to always evaluate them at all. If for row 1 it is found at runtime that A is false then no need to even evaluate B,C,D for that row.

Comment: @MartinSmith the predicates applied to the data not necessary look the same as you have put them in a query. You cannot say your expression is short circuited after it was rewritten for optimisation purposes. So the order of original operands does not matter, since mysql is free to evaluate them in any order it wants.

Comment: So is your argument then that MySQL can short circuit but just that it does so on the predicates after the optimisation stage?

Comment: @MartinSmith without doubts the "final" expression might be short circuited (as well as any evaluations in CPU can be as well), since it's just a boolean expression. The point is that the order of operands has no influence on that process, hence you cannot say that the order of them "short circuits" anything. And returning to the original question the only valid answer is "No", whereas this answer puts some hope (and misleading links, which in some places make stupid assumptions based on lack of knowledge).